# Why does "or at least" is usually preceded by a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas

This is from [independent.co.uk](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22or%20at%20least%22&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) (it showed up as a result on a website):

> You have probably read The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo, or at least heard of it.

*Or* is a coordinating conjunction, so grammatically speaking, it should only be preceded by a comma if what follows is a independent clause.

However, in the example above:

> or at least heard of it.

What follows is a dependent clause.

So why is there a comma before or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Options* are generally separated by commas.

**Example**

> You can have chicken, beef, or fish.

In your example there are two options: either you have *read* the book, or you have just *heard of it*.

> You have probably read The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo, or at least heard of it.

The two options are correctly separated by a comma.

Comment: I thought you should only do this if there were three or more options. Like they mention in this SE question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or. "When a coordinating conjunction is used to connect three or more items or clauses ..."

Comment: @alexchenco in the question and answer you cite, there are loads of examples with just two options. It says that a comma is appropriate when the two clauses are *independent*. So you could say "*You may have read the book or its sequel*" because both are about reading. In your example, the two clauses are not dependent because one is about reading and the other is about hearing of it.

Comment: The answer says that a comma should be used to join *two* independent clauses. In my example, I have an independent clause and a dependent clause. The last one is a dependent clause because it doesn't have a subject.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm not very sure about this, so correct me if I"m wrong.*

I did a research and found [this](https://theeditorsblog.net/2014/07/30/commas-with-subordinate-clauses-a-readers-question/) website. In it, they say:

> The adverbs of concession set up contrast clauses [...] Use commas to
>   introduce dependent clauses beginning with these words, even when the
>   independent clause comes first.

*Or at least* isn't in the list of adverbs of concession. But I suspect *or at least* acts as contrast in my example.

Same with sentences that use *let alone.* As mentioned in this [SE post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/the-phrase-let-alone):

> [...] prefaced by "let alone" shows what a reasonable person might expect in
>   contrast to the lesser option.

In short, another use of the comma is to show contrast.

Note: It could also be that the dependent clause is non-essential, like other poster mentioned. And therefore, it requires a comma.